# Filling a bar chart with colors that are weighted by data value using svg

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

Hi I'm trying to make it so the bar chart has decreasing shades of blue based on the data value. However my code is currently only changing the 1st bar. [Current chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njr5h.png)

```js
 d3.csv("GDP2016TrillionUSDollars.csv",function(error, data){
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.key = d.key;
        d.value = +d.value;
    });

   xScale.domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.key; }));
    yScale.domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.value; })]);
   
svg.selectAll('rect')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr("height", 0) 
        .attr("y", height)
        .attr({
            "x": function(d) { return xScale(d.key); },
            "y": function(d) { return yScale(d.value); },
            "width": xScale.rangeBand(),
            "height": function(d) { return  height - yScale(d.value); },
            // create increasing to decreasing shade of blue as shown on the output
             "fill": function(d) { return "rgb(0, 0, " +  (height - yScale(d.value)) + ")";}
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the code you pasted working, If you can use a working implementation I can help further. But for the fill property, trying using style and not attr as this could be overridden by CSS.

```
.style('fill', 
    function (d) { 
        return "rgb(0, 0, " +  (height - yScale(d.value)) + ")";
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing that black retangles is that you're passing non-integer values to the RGB. According to W3C:

> The format of an RGB value in the functional notation is 'rgb(' followed by a comma-separated list of three numerical values (either three **integer** values or three percentage values) followed by ')'. *(emphasis mine)*

Thus, just do this:

```
"fill": function(d) { return "rgb(0, 0, " +  Math.floor((height - yScale(d.value))) + ")";
```

That being said, manipulating RGB values can be a little complicated. I suggest that you create a scale for your colours, so you can easily change it the way you want:

```
var colours = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([minValue, maxValue])//your domain values go here
    .range(["gray", "blue"]);
//first colour--^     ^--last colour
```

And then using

```
.style("fill", function(d){ return colours(d.value)})
```

Check the demo:

```js
var w = 500, h = 200, padding = 20;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var data = [{name: "foo", value:50},
            {name: "bar", value:170},
            {name: "baz", value: 120},
           {name: "foobar", value:10},
           {name: "foobaz", value:70},
           {name: "barbaz", value:140}];

var colours = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 170])
  .range(["gray", "blue"]);

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0,w])
  .domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.name}))
  .paddingInner(0.2)
  .paddingOuter(0.2);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

var bars = svg.selectAll(".bars")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect");

bars.attr("x", function(d){ return xScale(d.name)})
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("y", function(d){ return (h - padding) - d.value})
  .attr("height", function(d){ return d.value})
  .style("fill", function(d){ return colours(d.value)})

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

PS: You're using v3, so change `scaleLinear()` to `scale.linear()`.